# How to use the table header instead of an exposed dropdown to sort a Views table?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view where the format display is a Table.

I exposed some field for sorting. The problem with that is, instead of activate the Table Header for the choosen sorting field in order to sort, that's created a dropdown where the user can choose the sorting field.

Is there a way to use to Table Header for sorting instead of this generated dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Table ***Setting*** and check the column ***Sortable*** of the field (like the image) and then click the ***Apply*** button and ***Save*** your view.

[image]

You will see the link in the table header

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend, that was the proper way to do it

Comment: @Jean-Francois a pleasure, god luck in your projects ;-)